# Process section of input URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Simple question really, but I'm probably missing a really simple point.

I have an input form, that a user will paste a URL in to be navigated to the next section.

Say the user enters in: `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=XXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBB&expires_in=0`

I want the form to only process the: `XXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBB`

So it will completely ignore:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=
```

and

```
&expires_in=0
```

Is this possible at all?

My form is incredibly simple:

```
<form action="home.php" method="GET">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Access Token.</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="accesstoken"/>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Confirm</button>
                </form>
```

"Bootstrap"

Thanks!

Comment: Process the URL on the server. Also, don't submit forms with `GET`, use `POST`

Comment: @JoshuaBrodie what do you mean? and I will use that in future, thanks!

Comment: The URL should be like `login_success.html?access_token=XYZAB&expires_in=0` for it to be recognized by `GET` (note the hash symbol has been replace with a question mark) if you cannot make it that way, you can save the URL into a variable and use string function to replace `#` with `?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much simpler solution to my issue:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
        var val = document.getElementById('exampleInputEmail1').value;
        $('#exampleInputEmail1').val(val.substring(val.indexOf("=") + 1, val.indexOf('&')));
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do an `explode`(https://www.php.net/explode) on the ampersand('&') and paste it together in a string or variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to use POST, like this:

```
<form action="home.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Access Token.</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="accesstoken"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

Then, you can retrieve your variable in PHP, like this:

```
<?php $accesstoken = $_GET['accesstoken']; ?>
```

which can easily be `echo`'ed into a JavaScript variable for your use.

Comment: Thanks, form has been updated, how would I implement the PHP section you mentioned, and would that then process only the access token?

Comment: @Billy : `login_success.html#access_token=` .  Its not .html?access_token !

Answer (score 0):

At first, I suggest you to parse it on server side, not client side (JavaScript can be turned off etc.). If you need to have `accesstoken` as GET parameter on `home.php`, you can redirect user here after submit. Anyway, on server side, try it with [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url):

```
$urlParts = parse_url($_POST['accesstoken']); // Now you have all URL parts in array
$urlQuery = $urlParts['query']; // Now you have only query part
$queryParts = explode('&', $urlQuery); // Separate them

foreach ($queryParts as $query)
{
   $singleQueryPart = explode('=', $query); // Separate key from value

   if ($singleQueryPart[0] == 'access_token') // If the key is same as we are looking for...
   {
      $token = $singleQueryPart[1]; // ...assign value and break loop
      break;
   }
}

echo $token;
```

**NOTE 1:** I assume that your URL in first post has type (`#` instead of `?`). If not, just use same script as I post, but change `$urlParts['query']` to `$urlParts['fragment']`.

**NOTE 2:** If you really want to/need to use JavaScript, look at [php.js implementation of parse_url](http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_url/).

**NOTE 3:** Another nice JS library to handle URL operations seems to be [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/).

Comment: Its `login_success.html#access_token=` Not `?access_token`

Comment: I've attempted using this now and still no luck, am I missing something incredibly obvious here?

Comment: Oh sorry, there was typo in my script, `accesstoken` instead of `access_token` on line 9.

Comment: And I just test it, it works for `#` and `?` too, just follow my **NOTE 1**.

Comment: @PavelŠtěrba do you have any other way I can contact you? I'd really like to get this resolved, thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly is your problem now? I tested my script, it works... For your data, there is some error, no output...?

Comment: I need to know where to enter in the code, on the landing page or in the form?

Comment: This script should handle your form (just change method from `GET` to `POST`). In your case, it should be in file `home.php`.

Comment: I made both of those amendments, but still nothing

Comment: When I change the form to 'POST', instead of 'GET', it modifies the URL on 'home.php', with 'GET', the URL is 'home.php?accesstoken=XXXXXXXXX' but when I tried 'POST', it just displays as 'home.php'

Comment: Yes, because it's now send via POST method, not via GET (which is visible in URL). This is why in my script is `$_POST['accesstoken']`, this is how you can access it with POST method.